# How to map Oracle SQL datatype NUMBER to Java type LONG

Tags: java, oracle

I have a custom VARRAY type:

```
create or replace TYPE ARRAY_NUMBERS AS VARRAY(1000000) OF NUMBER;
```

when I retrieve a result set of the ARRAY_NUMBERS type, JAVA is interpreting the numbers as `java.math.BigDecimal`, however I am expecting it to be a Long. 
Is there a way to do this?

```
 Error: 
 Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Could not set property 'ids' of 'class com.myproject.NumberValue' with value '[Ljava.math.BigDecimal;@d2037d' Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Comment: post your ibatis mapping file

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`longValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#longValue%28%29) method of `java.math.BigDecimal` to loop through the array and convert each number you have received from the database to a `long` type.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't ask the question correctly. What I really need is for it to be interpreted as a long before that